# HorizontalContentAlign="Stretch" and change highlight background color in listbox Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox

I'm developing some simple app for Windows Phone 8. I have a listbox and listbox item have two textblocks (one aligned to left and second to right side of screen). These textblocks are aligned with `<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>`. I found a way to change highlight color on active item here (change background color to accent color). My problem is that I can't use both solutions together. Stretch align is ignored and textblocks are aligned to left side when I did it this way:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="border" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

What I should do to get both solutions working together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you wrap the `ContentControl` within a `StackPanel`. Try changing the `StackPanel` to a `Grid`.

```
<Grid x:Name="border">
    <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

This is because `StackPanel` only takes as much space as it needs.